# Storing an array of custom objects in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I have an object called `List` which subclasses Realm's `Object` class:

```
class List: Object {
    dynamic var brandListItems: [BrandListItem] = []
}
```

and another object, `BrandListItem` which also subclasses to `Object`:

```
class BrandListItem: Object {
    dynamic var brandID: String?
    dynamic var name: String?
}
```

My app is crashing with the following error

> 'Property 'brandListItems' is declared as 'NSArray', which is not a supported RLMObject property type. All properties must be primitives, NSString, NSDate, NSData, NSNumber, RLMArray, RLMLinkingObjects, or subclasses of RLMObject.

I tried doing something like `RLMArray<BrandListItem>()` with no luck. How do I successfully save these objects to Realm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use Realm's `List<T>` property.  Note that it's not marked `dynamic`

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#to-many-relationships

```
class List: Object {
   let brandListItems = RealmSwift.List<BrandListItem>()
}
```

Note that it's necessary to qualify Realm Swift's `List<T>` with its module to disambiguate it from your newly-declared `List` class.

Comment: Also note that `List<T>` properties should be declared with `let` rather than `var`. And you'll likely run into problems creating a new class called `List` then trying to use Realm Swift's `List` within it. You'd either need to pick a different name for your class, or fully-qualify `RealmSwift.List<T>`.

Comment: Thanks @bdash. Why can't I do `var brandListItems = RealmSwift.List<BrandListItem>()` in the initial setup of the class and then in a failable initializer do `self.brandListItems = RealmSwift.List<BrandListItem>(array)` (where array is `[BrandListItem]`)

Comment: The reason that you should declare `List<T>` properties using `let` is that there's no way for Realm to intercept _assignment_ to properties of types that aren't compatible with Objective-C (for instance, any Swift generic type). Assigning to such a property will not result in the property's value being persisted. You should instead declare the property as `let brandListItems = RealmSwift.List<BrandListItem>()` and then _mutate_ the existing property value, (i.e., `self.brandListItems.append(contentsOf: array)`), within your initializer to populate it.